# MySQL query getting first columns data & MySQL query getting duplicate data

Tags: php, mysql

So my problem is that I'm trying to get all `first_name` from a `students` table, but when I do `mysqli_fetch_array` and output the results using `print_r()`1, it outputs only the first `first_name` in the table.

Students Table

```
students_id | first_name | last_name | teacher_id
1           | abc        | efg       | 10
2           | 123        | xyz       | 10
```

So the output is `Array ( [0] => wda [first_name] => wda )`. But I want it to output both the `first_name`.

Also I'm getting a duplicate of the same data.

Example

```
Array ( [0] => abc [first_name] => abc )
```

The array is storing `abc` twice, so how can I not get a duplicate of the data?

PHP Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Name Tags</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 

        require '../../connect.php';

        $results = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT first_name FROM students");

        if($results) {
            $results_arr = mysqli_fetch_array($results);

            print_r($results_arr);

            if(is_array($results_arr)) {
                foreach ($results_arr as $fname) {
                    echo "

                        <h1>$fname</h1>

                    ";
                }
            } else {
                echo '<h1>Empty</h1>';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Sorry, we ran into an error, please try again later.';
        }

     ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_array()` (and the other `mysqli_fetch_XXX()` functions) just returns one row of the results. You have to call it in a loop to get all the rows. You don't need to loop over this array, just access the columns you want.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $fname = $row['first_name'];
    echo "<h1>$fname</h1>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysqli_fetch_array() only retrieves a single row of output:

```
while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  print $r[0] . "<br />";
}
```